# Use async await in react component with redux-saga

Tags: reactjs, react-native, saga

Im working on a new RN application. In my sign in component, I have the following code.

```
const SignIn = ({ email, password, signInError, navigation, signInStart }: IProps) => {
  const handleLogin = async () => {
    const data = { email, password };
    await signInStart(data);

    if (signInError) {
      console.log('Error occured');
      return;
    }

    navigation.navigate(DASHBOARD_NAVIGATOR, { screen: 'Dashboard });
  };
```

If **signInStart(data)** fails, it sets an error on auth reducer. I want to check this redux state property (signInError) an navigate the user if there is no error. If there is an error, I want to display an error.

This is my saga.

```
function* signInStart({ payload }: any) {
  try {
    const response = yield call(AuthHttp.signIn, payload);
    const mappedResponse: IAuth = response.token;

    yield put(signInSuccess(mappedResponse));
    yield checkUserSessionStart();
  } catch (ex) {
    yield put(signInError(ex.error));
  }
}
```

The issue is, when I use async await with **handleLogin** in sign in component, try part  of the saga runs as expected but catch executes after executing the **handleLogin** function in sign in component.

This is confusing to me. How should I achieve this scenario properly? I want both try and catch in my saga to run before it goes to the next line of await in my component.